# Why can't I push_back an object into a vector of objects that belongs to another class?

Tags: c++

What I'm trying to do here is to add `Voter` to a `vector` that belongs to `RegLogBook` and, `RegLogBook` is an object that is owned by my `Election` class. I don't know what I'm doing wrong here, the `Voter` object is not being added to the `vector`. The relevant codes are below, I've removed all the unnecessary parts.

Election.h

```
class Election
{
public:
    Election();
    ~Election();
    RegLogBook getRegLogBook();
private:
    RegLogBook* _regLogBook;
};
```

Election.cpp

```
Election::Election()
{
    _regLogBook = new RegLogBook();
}

RegLogBook Election::getRegLogBook() {
    return *_regLogBook;
}
```

RegLogBook.h

```
class RegLogBook
{
public:
    RegLogBook();
    ~RegLogBook();
    vector<Voter*> getVoterList();

private:
    vector<Voter*> _voterList;
};
```

RegLogBook.cpp

```
vector<Voter*> RegLogBook::getVoterList() {
    return _voterList;
}
```

Committee.cpp register voter method

```
void Committee::RegVoter(RegLogBook logs) {
    Voter *newVoter = new Voter();
    logs.getVoterList().push_back(newVoter); //The voter is not added to the list
}
```

I call this in my main()

```
Election *Election2018 = new Election();
Committee com1 = new Committee();
com1.RegVoter(Election2018->getRegLogBook());
```

Comment: There must be a 1000 and a one duplicate, but I do not know how to look for them. In short, you are returning a **copy** of a member variable, and when you insert data in it, the original remains unchanged.

Comment: offtopic: seems like you should have a `std::vector<Voter>` rather than a `std::vector<Voter*>`

Comment: Did you learn Java or C# previously? It's not good idea to draw parallels between C++ and those languages, because they work in different ways on basic level. I'd recommend [a good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to learn

Comment: @SergeyA *but I do not know how to look for them* --  Probably because a lot of the questions start out as "why are my iterators invalid?", with the answer being that copies are returned from a `get...()` function instead of a reference.  So it's probably hard to pinpoint a duplicate if the question starts out not sounding like the OP's.

Comment: Are you learning C++ from a book?  Since you don't appear to need polymorphic behavior, get rid of all those pointers (`Type*`) and dynamic allocations (`new Type`).

Answer (score 6):

`RegLogBook::getVoterList()` returns your `_voterList` by **value**. That means it copies the whole vector and returns it. Then you add elements to that copy.

To fix this, simply change your

```
vector<Voter*> RegLogBook::getVoterList()
```

to

```
vector<Voter*>& RegLogBook::getVoterList()
//            ^ notice the reference part
```

There is another problem that I initially missed. In your `Committee::RegVoter` method, you take the argument *by value*. That means the method will be invoked with a *copy of your `RegLogBook`*. You should also change

```
void Committee::RegVoter(RegLogBook logs)
```

to

```
void Committee::RegVoter(RegLogBook& logs)
//      again notice the reference ^
```

<sub>*Thanks to **Lightness Races in Orbit** for pointing that out*</sub>

Remember - to work on the original object, not a copy of it, you should pass it either by a *reference* or a *pointer*. By default you should prefer passing by reference, unless you have strong argument to use pointers

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that you return the voter list by-value, meaning that a copy of the voter list is returned:

```
vector<Voter*> RegLogBook::getVoterList() {
    return _voterList;
}
```

So this line:

```
logs.getVoterList().push_back(newVoter);
```

will modify *the local copy* instead of the value being stored in the object instance.

Try modifying your code to return a *reference* (by changing the return type to be `vector<Voter*>&`)

```
vector<Voter*>& RegLogBook::getVoterList() {
    return _voterList;
}
```

or, maybe better, return a pointer:

```
vector<Voter*>* RegLogBook::getVoterList() {
    return &_voterList;
}
```

I prefer the last alternative, as this makes it more obvious that the returned value can be modified.

Comment: reference or pointer have the same meaning regarding the returned value can be modified, but pointers can be null which is the wrong thing unless the value returned actually can be `null`

Comment: Your last point is quite similar to claiming that you should prefer passing arguments by pointers rather than by reference, so it's obvious they are not copied. This is discouraged in every major C++ guideline. One should prefer the **first** solution here (*thanks **user463035818** for pointing out the typo in the original comment*)

Comment: Most of the time, mutating a return value seems like a bad idea and mutation, in general, is a source of many bugs. I believe this is the reason why the Google C++ style guide (https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Output_Parameters) discourages output parameters for functions, but if they have to be used, as pointer arguments (as opposed to a reference). This makes it clear at the call site that the argument is expected to be modified. By returning a pointer as opposed to a reference, it is also much more obvious that we are not modifying a local copy.

Answer (score 0):

From what I'm seeing your code shouldn't even compile: you're using the `new` keyword, but you're saving its returned value into a `Committee`, not into a `Committee*` as you should. If you are using an overloaded `new` operator, please post the whole code.